Verifying Mailjet contact upload to a single list efficiently
I'm using Mailjet to upload contacts to a specific list in chunks. Each chunk generates a job ID. However, I'd like to avoid manually checking the job ID for verification.
Is there a way to efficiently confirm that all uploaded contacts have been successfully added to the target list without iterating through the job ID?
Here are some potential approaches:
Does Mailjet offer a post-upload confirmation message indicating success?
Can I use the contacts endpoint with filters to retrieve newly added contacts and compare the count to the uploaded data?
Are there webhooks or notifications that trigger upon successful completion of the entire upload process for a single list?
My goal is to automate the verification process and streamline it for single-list uploads.
